# how to upload a JAR file to github

Tags: java, git, maven, github, jar

For homebrew applications, where a maven repository is overkill, or at least **not desired**, how can a JAR be uploaded to github?

When I try to upload a JAR file through the web interface, github replies that JAR files aren't supported.  Since ZIP files are allowed, I suppose a JAR could be compressed as a ZIP file, or, even simpler, just append `.zip` to the name.

However, then it's still another step to convert the ZIP to JAR, even if that's just a matter of removing `.zip` from the name.

How does this repo:

https://github.com/asterisk-java/asterisk-java/releases

host JAR files?  Just by using git `git add foo.jar`?

**Notably, there's an actual button labeled "latest release".**

(This is in the context of maven and gradle builds.)

Comment: When you create create a release, you can attach binaries of any kind, including JAR files. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Strange, I was able to upload a JAR through the web interface: https://github.com/THUFIR/noagenda/tree/releases and its there.  Last time I tried that, github said that only ZIP, PDF, and a few others were supported -- not JAR.  At least through the web interface.  By **release** you mean a **branch** named "release<version>"?

Comment: By release I mean when you create a new release in the releases page, like here: https://github.com/THUFIR/noagenda/releases

Comment: So weird.  I thought that JAR files weren't allowed, but it works fine.  Not sure where I got that idea from...thanks.  Answer accepted!  This is basically adding a JAR to the repo itself?  Not the best practice, but works :)